# performance issue: Generating many blob shared access signatures is very slow

Tags: performance, azure-blob-storage

we have a site running on azure. we use azure storage service to store our static content  (images, videos, and so on).

we have a page in which we display a table with a list of items, and for each item we display a thumbnail image. The thumbnails are stored in the storage service, and we allocate a shared access signature for each one using a code as follows:

```
...
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
if (!CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(connectionString, out storageAccount))
{
    throw new Exception("...");
}
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

var policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
{
    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
    SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5),
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10)
};

var signature = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);

return blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + signature;
...
```

This is done in a loop, allocating a distinct SAS for each image in the list. However, as the list grows there's a very big performance downgrade. For more 10-20 images, the page takes very long time to load). The same page without the SAS generation loads immediately.

Is there a way to quicken this?

thanx,

Comment: both the web site and the storage are in the same geo location

Answer (score 4):

In the code above I repeatedly get a reference to the container. This causes a grave performance penalty. To resolve, i store the containers in a private cache and get them only once.